# On the convergence of particular sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm reading Knopp's book on infinite series. Chapter $2$ which ends with the main results on convergent sequences (not series), suggests the following excercises (the author assumes known the simplest results with regard to logarithms and the numbers $e$ and $\pi$, although he doesn't say which ones):

> \begin{align*}
> \left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right) +\ ...\ +\log\left(1+\frac{n}{n^2}\right)\right] &\to 1/2\\
> \left[\frac{n}{n^2+1^2}+\ ... \ +\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}\right] &\to \pi/4\\
> \frac{1}{n}\sqrt[n]{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+n)} &\to 4/e\\
> \left[\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^n+\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n+\ ... \ +\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right] &\to \frac{e}{e-1}
> \end{align*}

I have no idea how to prove even one of these. The first one boils down to: $$(1+1/n^2)(1+2/n^2)...(1+n/n^2) \to e^{1/2},$$
but from here i don't know how to proceed. The second one assumes some formulas on $\pi$, the only ones I know are $\sum1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$ or $\sum(-1)^n/(2n+1) = \pi/4$. Third also can be rewritten in terms of logarithms. Fourth I should be able to prove after you give me some hints on the methods.
I'm assuming that $n$ is a positive integer. Each term in the bracket is a term of the sequence for that particular value of $n$.

Comment: They are all riemann sums of functions

Comment: how about the first one?

Answer (score 1):

Hint :

1- $\pi/4=\int_{0}^{1} \frac1{1+x^2}dx= lim  \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} 1/n \frac1{1^2+(k/n)^2}=lim  \sum_{k=1}^{k=n} \frac n {n^2+k^2} $

Comment: Can you help me with the first also?